# Django connection to Redis

Tags: python, django, redis

To connect Django to Redis, I have to open connection for each view:

```
import redis
cacheDB = redis.StrictRedis()
cacheDB.sadd("new_post", post.id)
```

Is there a way to create a single connection somewhere and import it into each view?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [django-redis](http://niwibe.github.io/django-redis/), which allows using Redis as the backend for Django's cache framework. It supports [connection pooling](http://niwibe.github.io/django-redis/#_connection_pools).

Basic usage:

```
# settings.py
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'redis_cache.cache.RedisCache',
        'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:6379:1',
    }
}
```

Then you can use it in your view code:

```
from django.core.cache import cache
cache.set('foo', 'bar')
```

For `sadd` you can use the raw Redis client:

```
>>> from django_redis import get_redis_connection
>>> con = get_redis_connection('default')
>>> con
<redis.client.Redis object at 0x2dc4510>
```